# How to use GitHub Repo using JitPack.io in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, jitpack

I wants to use https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase version 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT

I have added the following in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

<repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

but got following error when compile:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XYZ: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.XYZ:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT in https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of liquibase-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with JitPack and downloading this repository. According to [the maven modular example](https://github.com/jitpack/maven-modular) that JitPack provides, the dependency should be defined as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.User.Repo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Module</artifactId>
    <version>Commit/Tag</version>
</dependency>
```

The following should then work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.liquibase.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>f7f3b8f60b</version>
</dependency>
```

But it also fails resolving the dependency:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.github.liquibase.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:0885bc4 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

You can see that this is definitely an issue by just trying to use the liquibase parent repository (not just the liquibase-core module) as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>f7f3b8f60b</version>
</dependency>
```

Which also errors out. According to [JitPack's log](https://jitpack.io/com/github/liquibase/liquibase/master-liquibase-parent-3.4.2-g0885bc4-236/build.log) for this commit, it looks like there is a compilation error with the source:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project liquibase-core: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] /home/jitpack/build/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.
> java:[213,209] ')' expected

It seems like the best route would be to [file an issue](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/new?title=liquibase/master-liquibase-parent-3.4.2-g0885bc4-236%20build&body=Log%20https://jitpack.io/com/github/liquibase/liquibase/master-liquibase-parent-3.4.2-g0885bc4-236/build.log) with the JitPack folks and see if they can shed some light on it.

Comment: JitPack mail me there was a closing bracket ')' missing in code, that's why compilation was failing. Anyways I rectified liquibase code and submit it on GIT.

Comment: Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong? I am still getting the error after comitting the code in github pleace check: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/7849d1a0c8f0f11e6c8efe69706bd667cdb24a56

Comment: added the following in pom:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>7849d1a</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Please tell How can i  check the log.thanks advance.

Comment: It looks like it won't work until they merge your change in. You could link it directly to your own repository in the meantime though using the XML at the following link: https://jitpack.io/#com.github.asadyarkhan007.liquibase/liquibase-core/patch-1-SNAPSHOT