# Can't build using JitPack.io

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

I am trying

```
<!-- https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java.git -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.lbehnke</groupId>
<artifactId>hierarchical-clustering-java</artifactId>
<version>anyBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

is that the right way to use it?

I've added

```
<repository>
<id>jitpack.io</id>
<url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

and I am trying to build from inside eclipse
(of course it's a maven project)

error says

```
Missing artifact com.github.lbehnke:hierarchical-clustering-
java:jar:anyBranch-SNAPSHOT
```

and

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing 
library '/home/leoks/.m2/repository/com/github/lbehnke/hierarchical-
clustering-java/anyBranch-SNAPSHOT/hierarchical-clustering-
java-anyBranch-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

ps. I've already checked these threads

[How to use GitHub Repo using JitPack.io in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930820/how-to-use-github-repo-using-jitpack-io-in-maven)

[Can I use a GitHub project directly in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871056/can-i-use-a-github-project-directly-in-maven)

But none seems to help

[image]

Comment: Why not depend on the 1.1.0 release version? https://jitpack.io/#lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java/v1.1.0

Comment: tried that already

Comment: What if you use -SNAPSHOT version without 'anyBranch'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the version id for the tag id in your dependency.

So in your case, for version v1.1.0 the tag id is d74af46. Found at: Repository page -> releases -> lefthand column (under the version id).

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.lbehnke</groupId>
<artifactId>hierarchical-clustering-java</artifactId>
<version>d74af46</version>
</dependency>
```

This doesn't gives you the SNAPSHOT version but at least should compile. I tested here and it worked.

Source: https://github.com/vidstige/jadb/issues/14